# How to force skydrive offline to get the 'offline' experience

Tags: office365, onedrive

My goal is to open (in Windows) an office document and not make a round trip to office 365. This round trip, on a slow connection, can be 30-seconds. If I disable my network adapter, then I get the 'offline' experience; immediate loading of documents.

Does anyone know a setting or script to force the skydrive syncing service to go offline without disabling the NA.

I also need the best Microsoft site to ask for this feature to be implemented?

Anyone else struggling with this?

Comment: Can you not just block it in your firewall?

Comment: I decided to use a .bat file to toggle my network adapter using `Netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" disable` then 'Netsh interface set interface "Wi-Fi" enable'. To work around needing to run as administrator [windows 8], I created a shortcut to my desktop and checked the 'Run as administrator' in the Advanced settings. I created another pair of bat files for my LAN adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You could block the connection to Office365 through your firewall (easier, by simply blocking Office) or with the `hosts` file, however first you'd need to figure out what address to block (if using the `hosts` file).